# Wine on Linux Mint - too many "fixme" messages

Tags: linux, mono, linux-mint, wine, linux-mint-20

I'm trying to run a windows app on Linux Mint 20.03.
Wine installed Mono to install the app since it uses .NET. When launching the app from the terminal, I've got all of these messages:

```
01a4:fixme:iphlpapi:NotifyAddrChange (Handle 000000000081F1E8, overlapped 0000019800034090): stub
01a4:fixme:win:GetPointerDevices (000000000081EB0C 0000000000000000): partial stub
01a4:fixme:system:QueryDisplayConfig (00000002 000000000081EB20 00000198047BFE20 000000000081EB10 00000198000BF100 0000000000000000): semi-stub
01a4:fixme:system:DisplayConfigGetDeviceInfo Unimplemented packet type: 11
01a4:fixme:win:GetPointerDevices (000000000081EB0C 0000000000000000): partial stub
01a4:fixme:system:QueryDisplayConfig (00000002 000000000081EB20 00000198047BFE20 000000000081EB10 00000198000BF100 0000000000000000): semi-stub
01a4:fixme:system:DisplayConfigGetDeviceInfo Unimplemented packet type: 11
01a4:fixme:win:GetPointerDevices (000000000081EB0C 0000000000000000): partial stub
01a4:fixme:system:QueryDisplayConfig (00000002 000000000081EB20 00000198047BFE20 000000000081EB10 00000198000BF100 0000000000000000): semi-stub
01a4:fixme:system:DisplayConfigGetDeviceInfo Unimplemented packet type: 11
021c:fixme:wtsapi:WTSRegisterSessionNotification Stub 0000000000020074 0x00000000
0228:fixme:winstation:GetUserObjectSecurity (0000000000000008 000000000FCFEF28 0000000000000000 len=0 000000000FCFEF2C),stub!
0228:fixme:winstation:GetUserObjectSecurity (0000000000000008 000000000FCFEF28 000001980497F0B0 len=40 000000000FCFEF2C),stub!
0228:fixme:ntdll:NtSetInformationToken TokenIntegrityLevel stub!
0228:fixme:ntdll:NtFilterToken flags 0x1 unsupported
0228:fixme:ntdll:NtFilterToken support for restricting sids not yet implemented
01a4:fixme:service:I_ScRegisterDeviceNotification Notification filters are not yet implemented.
01a4:fixme:wtsapi:WTSRegisterSessionNotification Stub 0000000000030042 0x00000000
0228:fixme:sync:NtSetInformationJobObject stub: 0x32c 4 0xfcff028 4
0230:fixme:file:ReplaceFileW Ignoring flags 2
01a4:fixme:combase:RoGetActivationFactory (L"Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceAccessInformation", {574bd3d3-5f30-45cd-8a94-724fe5973084}, 000000000081CB00): semi-stub
01a4:err:combase:RoGetActivationFactory Failed to find library for L"Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceAccessInformation"
01a4:fixme:combase:RoGetActivationFactory (L"Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceAccessInformation", {574bd3d3-5f30-45cd-8a94-724fe5973084}, 000000000081CB00): semi-stub
01a4:err:combase:RoGetActivationFactory Failed to find library for L"Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceAccessInformation"
01a4:fixme:system:EnableNonClientDpiScaling (0000000000030040): stub
01a4:fixme:win:RegisterTouchWindow (0000000000030040 00000002): stub
021c:fixme:wtsapi:WTSRegisterSessionNotification Stub 000000000002004E 0x00000000
01a4:fixme:dwmapi:DwmSetWindowAttribute (0000000000030040, 2, 000000000081C584, 4) stub
01a4:fixme:nls:RtlGetThreadPreferredUILanguages 00000038, 000000000081B94C, 0000000000000000 000000000081B948
01a4:fixme:nls:get_dummy_preferred_ui_language (0x38 000000000081B94C 0000000000000000 000000000081B948) returning a dummy value (current locale)
01a4:fixme:nls:RtlGetThreadPreferredUILanguages 00000038, 000000000081B94C, 000000000081B932 000000000081B948
01a4:fixme:nls:get_dummy_preferred_ui_language (0x38 000000000081B94C 000000000081B932 000000000081B948) returning a dummy value (current locale)
01a4:fixme:dwrite:dwritefontface5_HasVariations 0000000001775CE0: stub
01a4:fixme:win:RegisterPowerSettingNotification (000000000002004E,{2b84c20e-ad23-4ddf-93db-05ffbd7efca5},0): stub
0254:err:winediag:ntlm_check_version ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
0254:err:ntlm:ntlm_LsaApInitializePackage no NTLM support, expect problems
0254:fixme:powrprof:PowerRegisterSuspendResumeNotification (0x00000002,000000000081FCF0,000000000081FCE8) stub!
0254:fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation 0000000000000000 1 0000000000000000 0 stub
0254:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventSetInformation (deadbeef, 2, 00000212002410B0, 16) stub
027c:fixme:winsock:WSALookupServiceBeginW (0000000006ACDBE0 0x00000ff0 0000000006ACDC58) Stub!
027c:fixme:iphlpapi:NotifyAddrChange (Handle 0000000006ACDDB8, overlapped 0000021200310B10): stub
027c:fixme:wlanapi:WlanEnumInterfaces (0000000000000001, 0000000000000000, 0000000006ACCD88) semi-stub
027c:fixme:wlanapi:WlanEnumInterfaces (0000000000000001, 0000000000000000, 0000000006ACCD88) semi-stub
01a4:fixme:shcore:GetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID 000000000081BC90: stub
0298:fixme:file:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
0298:fixme:heap:PrefetchVirtualMemory process FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, count 0000000000000001, addresses 000000000A3CF400, flags 0 stub.
027c:fixme:winsock:setsockopt Ignoring SO_RANDOMIZE_PORT
01a4:fixme:win:RegisterTouchWindow (0000000000020070 00000002): stub
0228:fixme:winstation:GetUserObjectSecurity (0000000000000008 000000000FCFEF28 0000000000000000 len=0 000000000FCFEF2C),stub!
0228:fixme:winstation:GetUserObjectSecurity (0000000000000008 000000000FCFEF28 000001980497EC00 len=40 000000000FCFEF2C),stub!
0228:fixme:ntdll:NtSetInformationToken TokenIntegrityLevel stub!
0228:fixme:ntdll:NtFilterToken flags 0x1 unsupported
0228:fixme:ntdll:NtFilterToken support for restricting sids not yet implemented
027c:fixme:wlanapi:WlanEnumInterfaces (0000000000000001, 0000000000000000, 0000000006ACCA88) semi-stub
02a8:err:winediag:ntlm_check_version ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
02a8:err:ntlm:ntlm_LsaApInitializePackage no NTLM support, expect problems
02a8:fixme:powrprof:PowerRegisterSuspendResumeNotification (0x00000002,000000000081FCF0,000000000081FCE8) stub!
02a8:fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation 0000000000000000 1 0000000000000000 0 stub
02a8:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventSetInformation (deadbeef, 2, 000002B6002410B0, 16) stub
02a8:fixme:ntdll:NtQuerySystemInformation info_class SYSTEM_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION
02a8:fixme:thread:QueryThreadCycleTime (FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE,000000000081EB48): stub!
02f8:fixme:kernelbase:AppPolicyGetThreadInitializationType FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFA, 000000000D48FE10
0228:fixme:winstation:GetUserObjectSecurity (0000000000000008 000000000FCFEF28 0000000000000000 len=0 000000000FCFEF2C),stub!
0228:fixme:winstation:GetUserObjectSecurity (0000000000000008 000000000FCFEF28 000001980497EED0 len=40 000000000FCFEF2C),stub!
0228:fixme:ntdll:NtSetInformationToken TokenIntegrityLevel stub!
0228:fixme:ntdll:NtFilterToken flags 0x1 unsupported
0228:fixme:ntdll:NtFilterToken support for restricting sids not yet implemented
027c:fixme:ntdll:NtQuerySystemInformation info_class SYSTEM_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION
0228:fixme:winstation:GetUserObjectSecurity (0000000000000008 000000000FCFEF28 0000000000000000 len=0 000000000FCFEF2C),stub!
0228:fixme:winstation:GetUserObjectSecurity (0000000000000008 000000000FCFEF28 000001980497E480 len=40 000000000FCFEF2C),stub!
0228:fixme:ntdll:NtSetInformationToken TokenIntegrityLevel stub!
0228:fixme:ntdll:NtFilterToken flags 0x1 unsupported
0228:fixme:ntdll:NtFilterToken support for restricting sids not yet implemented
0228:fixme:winstation:GetUserObjectSecurity (0000000000000008 000000000FCFEF28 0000000000000000 len=0 000000000FCFEF2C),stub!
0228:fixme:winstation:GetUserObjectSecurity (0000000000000008 000000000FCFEF28 000001980497E270 len=40 000000000FCFEF2C),stub!
0228:fixme:ntdll:NtSetInformationToken TokenIntegrityLevel stub!
0228:fixme:ntdll:NtFilterToken flags 0x1 unsupported
0228:fixme:ntdll:NtFilterToken support for restricting sids not yet implemented
027c:fixme:winsock:setsockopt Ignoring SO_RANDOMIZE_PORT
0228:fixme:winstation:GetUserObjectSecurity (0000000000000008 000000000FCFEF28 0000000000000000 len=0 000000000FCFEF2C),stub!
0228:fixme:winstation:GetUserObjectSecurity (0000000000000008 000000000FCFEF28 0000019804CB30C0 len=40 000000000FCFEF2C),stub!
0228:fixme:ntdll:NtSetInformationToken TokenIntegrityLevel stub!
0228:fixme:ntdll:NtFilterToken flags 0x1 unsupported
0228:fixme:ntdll:NtFilterToken support for restricting sids not yet implemented
0228:fixme:winstation:GetUserObjectSecurity (0000000000000008 000000000FCFEF28 0000000000000000 len=0 000000000FCFEF2C),stub!
0228:fixme:winstation:GetUserObjectSecurity (0000000000000008 000000000FCFEF28 0000019804B93260 len=40 000000000FCFEF2C),stub!
0228:fixme:ntdll:NtSetInformationToken TokenIntegrityLevel stub!
0228:fixme:ntdll:NtFilterToken flags 0x1 unsupported
0228:fixme:ntdll:NtFilterToken support for restricting sids not yet implemented
0228:fixme:winstation:GetUserObjectSecurity (0000000000000008 000000000FCFEF28 0000000000000000 len=0 000000000FCFEF2C),stub!
0228:fixme:winstation:GetUserObjectSecurity (0000000000000008 000000000FCFEF28 000001980497EC60 len=40 000000000FCFEF2C),stub!
0228:fixme:ntdll:NtSetInformationToken TokenIntegrityLevel stub!
0228:fixme:ntdll:NtFilterToken flags 0x1 unsupported
0228:fixme:ntdll:NtFilterToken support for restricting sids not yet implemented
02a8:fixme:dwrite:dwritefontface5_HasVariations 00000000016A40A0: stub
0228:fixme:winstation:GetUserObjectSecurity (0000000000000008 000000000FCFEF28 0000000000000000 len=0 000000000FCFEF2C),stub!
0228:fixme:winstation:GetUserObjectSecurity (0000000000000008 000000000FCFEF28 0000019804F197B0 len=40 000000000FCFEF2C),stub!
0228:fixme:ntdll:NtSetInformationToken TokenIntegrityLevel stub!
0228:fixme:ntdll:NtFilterToken flags 0x1 unsupported
0228:fixme:ntdll:NtFilterToken support for restricting sids not yet implemented
01f0:fixme:ntdll:NtQuerySystemInformation info_class SYSTEM_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION
01dc:fixme:kernelbase:AppPolicyGetProcessTerminationMethod FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFA, 000000000081FD40
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: You can use search engines to learn more about Wine and why as an open source project it comes with many bad parts. Mono on Wine is extremely a vulnerable piece, as it was not offered by the original Mono developers, so you are on your own. Unless you are capable of supporting yourself on both Mono and Wine, I suggest you stay on Windows for such apps.